# Inout argument could be set to a value with a type other than 'CHILD', use a value declared as type 'PARENT' instead

Tags: swift, oop

I am trying to design an abstract class in swift, within which a function takes an instance of a child of that class. However, I want to specify the type of the argument as the name of the abstract class, since I don't know which child of the class would be passed. Example code:

```
protocol Character {
...
}
extension Character {
...
   mutating func fight(target: inout Character) {
      target.hp -= 10
   }
}
struct Warrior: Character {
...
}
struct Mage: Character {
...
}
foo = Warrior()
bar = Mage()
foo.fight(target: bar)
```

Here in this code I get the error: `Inout argument could be set to a value with a type other than 'Mage', use a value declared as type 'Character' instead`, meaning the compiler is not able to regocnize that Mage implements Character and therefore is of type character. How do I solve this?

Comment: What is `RPGCharacter`?

Comment: @PhillipMills my bad, fixed it

Comment: why am I being downvoted? this is a perfectly valid OOP question for swift. I am trying to pass a mutable argument of a type that implements a protocol, with the parameter being defined as having type of said protocol.

Comment: Note that there is absolutely no OO whatsoever here. There are no (abstract) classes, no inheritance, no objects, no children. These are structs and protocols, and while they may look similar, they are entirely different beasts.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming your code looks something like this:

```
extension Character {
    mutating func fight(target: inout Character) {
        target.hp -= 10
    }
}

var foo = Warrior()
var bar = Mage()

foo.fight(target: &bar)
```

The problem is that your `bar` variable is inferred to be of type `Mage` which you can't pass as an inout argument to a function that takes `Character`.

To understand why this limitation exists, imagine that your `fight` function had this implementation:

```
mutating func fight(target: inout Character) {
    target = Warrior()
}
```

If passing a variable of type `Mage` to that function was valid then you would be assigning a value of type `Warrior` to a variable of type `Mage` which obviously can't work.

If you want to pass `bar` to your function then you would need to declare it as:

```
var bar: Character = Mage()
```

Another way to do it would be to make your `fight` function generic which would work with your original calling code but would have other limitations:

```
mutating func fight<T: Character>(target: inout T) {
    target.hp -= 10
}
```

Comment: using `target = Warrior()` seems fine to me. Warrior is still of type Character. That'd be a stupid thing to do, and should result in an error later if the user calls a method defined in Mage after converting target to Warrior, but it should not disallowed. I guess I expected Swift to cast Mage to Character when it's being passed as a parameter.

Comment: i can't use `var bar: Character = Mage()` because then I would not have access to Mage's methods. I can cast it, but then that'd make it immutable.

Comment: I tried using generics, but I'm actually getting the same error still.

Comment: Note that if you use the generics approach, you'll have to use `foo.fight(target: &bar)`. wfm this way.

Comment: I'll post my playground example as another answer, too much code for a comment...

Comment: Using a generic specifies the type of the value you're passing. Not all `Character` implementations are equal and they are not interchangeable, that's why you need to specialize the function with a generic.

Comment: @Gereon thank you for posting the full example, I got it working now. But, couldn't I still do the same thing that was not allowed previously, like setting `target = Warrior()`? How does using a generic solve this problem?

Comment: No, the compiler will reject that with `Cannot assign value of type 'Warrior' to type 'T'` (likewise with Mage). You *could* have `target = T()` in `fight`, but that's type-safe.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on @dan's suggestion to use generics, I tried this successfully in an Xcode 11.5 playground

```
protocol Character {
    var hp: Int { get set }
}

extension Character {
    mutating func fight<T: Character>(target: inout T) {
        target.hp -= 10
    }
}

struct Warrior: Character {
    var hp = 40
}

struct Mage: Character {
    var hp = 20
}

var foo = Warrior()
var bar = Mage()

foo.fight(target: &bar)
print(bar.hp) // 10
```